# Count of bytes vs Count of Chars

Tags: c, windows, string, api, api-design

Some apis requires **count of chars.**

```
// Why did they choose cch in these functions.
HRESULT StringCchCopyW(
  __out  LPWSTR pszDest,
  __in   size_t cchDest,
  __in   LPCWSTR pszSrc
);

errno_t wcscpy_s(
   wchar_t *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const wchar_t *strSource 
);

DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentDirectoryW(
  __in   DWORD nBufferLength, // Count of Chars
  __out  LPWSTR lpBuffer
);
```

And Some apis requires **count of bytes.**

```
// What do you prefer cch vs cb function.
// Do cch functions almost useful?
HRESULT StringCbCopyW(
  __out  LPWSTR pszDest,
  __in   size_t cbDest,
  __in   LPCWSTR pszSrc
);

BOOL WINAPI ReadFile(
  __in         HANDLE hFile,
  __out        LPVOID lpBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  __inout_opt  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);

// Why did they choose cb in these structures.
// Because there are some apis uses cb, I always should see MSDN.
typedef struct _LSA_UNICODE_STRING {
  USHORT Length; // Count of bytes.
  USHORT MaximumLength; // Count of bytes.
  PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _FILE_RENAME_INFO {
  BOOL   ReplaceIfExists;
  HANDLE RootDirectory;
  DWORD  FileNameLength; // Count of bytes.
  WCHAR  FileName[1];
} FILE_RENAME_INFO, *PFILE_RENAME_INFO;
```

When you design a function or a data structure, how do you determine cb or cch? And why?
To design better api for caller, what should I know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data returned is a string, you should return the count of chars, since the number of bytes is often useless. But if it's generic binary data (and not specifically a string), then obviously the number of chars doesn't make any sense, so use the number of bytes.

As to why:

I believe the reason for `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` holding the number of bytes is that it's meant to be compatible with `UNICODE_STRING`, which in turn is used in [NtCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But `NtCreateFile` takes in a `FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID` parameter that actually treats the `UNICODE_STRING` to be pointing to a `LONGLONG` value, and *not* a string... so the number of bytes made more sense there, although I'd say it was overall a poor design:

> FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID: The file name that is specified by the `ObjectAttributes` parameter includes the 8-byte file reference number for the file.

Comment: Explanation of UNICODE_STRING is very nice.

Comment: *the number of bytes is often useless.* Why? Could you explain more about this?

Comment: @Benjamin: Well, I meant it's often useless if you already have the number of chars, since usually the whole point of the length is to do array-bounds checking. The "often" breaks down in those cases where you're treating the string as raw binary data, but it doesn't happen too often, and you can -- if needed -- just multiply the char count by `sizeof(str[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the first group of functions you mention are all ASCII functions, and so in that case there is no difference - the count of bytes is the count of characters. That is because (generally, anyway) a single ASCII character is exactly one byte in size.

The second group are unicode functions/structs. In this case, the characters are not guaranteed to be only a single byte in size - if in UTF16 format they'll be two bytes wide, in UTF32 they'll be four, and in UTF8 they'll (typically) be anywhere from one to four bytes wide.

Particularly with the case of UTF8 data, if you create a buffer usually you set aside a certain number of **bytes**, which depending on character sizes could be quite a variety of lengths in terms of character counts. I'm not overly familiar with most of the functions/structs you've presented, but it wouldn't surprise me if that has something to do with it.

To answer your question, if you're working with ASCII you can use either approach - it makes no difference. If working with variable-length encodings however (such as UTF8), whether you use one or the other depends on whether you are interested in just the characters involved, or whether you also need to take into account their encoding.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the functions to Unicode. That's what I intended.

Comment: No worries! I'll still stand by my final paragraph though - the **characters** are not the same thing as the **encoding**, and so what you do will most likely depend on whether you need to take into account the underlying character encoding.